# Invisible to Transparent HTML/CSS Button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

Ok. So I'm trying to re create this really cool looking button that I found. The example is at http://gyazo.com/cafe378e8340d71c341b7c52857b2689 See how it is first invisible but now it's faded a little bit? Here is my version so far.  ->  Please try to help on this! <3

HTML

```
<button>METRO 5.2</button>
```

CSS

```
body {
  background-image: url(http://p1.pichost.me/i/39/1624496.jpg);
  text-align: center;
}
button {
  border: 1;
  background: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 1px;
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-right: 60px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  color: #FFF
}

button:hover {
  padding-left: 80px;
  padding-right: 80px;
  background-color: #bdc3c7;
  background: 0.4;
}
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/iKornn/pen/JdWbZW

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yak613/7t9rndh9/

Comment: @Yak613 make an answer with your solution so iKornn can mark it as correct, so people stop coming here!

Answer (score 0):

index.html:

```
<button>METRO 5.2</button>
```

and Your CSS .. Style.css:

```
body {
  background-image: url(http://p1.pichost.me/i/39/1624496.jpg);
  text-align: center;
}
button {
  border: 1;
  background: rgba(189, 195, 199, .1);
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 1px;
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-right: 60px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  color: #FFF
}

button:hover {
  padding-left: 80px;
  padding-right: 80px;
  background-color: rgba(189, 195, 199, 1);
  background: 0.4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<button>METRO 5.2</button>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-image: url(http://p1.pichost.me/i/39/1624496.jpg);
  text-align: center;
}
button {
  border: 1 solid #FFF;
  background: rgba(189, 195, 199, .1);
  border-radius: 1px;
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-right: 60px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  color: #FFF
}

button:hover {
  padding-left: 80px;
  padding-right: 80px;
  background-color: rgba(189, 195, 199, 1);
  background: 0.4;
}
```